# Xcode iOS App Store publishing - Code signing

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

i am trying to update an allready published app of my company because the certificates run out of lifetime.

Now, after creating a new Certificate for Publishing iOS Apps, creating a new Distribution profile and so on, Xcode throws the following error message:

[image]

Does someone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

"Automatically manage signing" will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: well, no. Pressing this mysterious button says, that Xcode weren't able to create a development profile.
And wether he would create one or not, i do only want to publish this application, not to create an development profile